# Python iterate over linux command output, line by line in real-time

Tags: python, linux, pipe

I've seen a lot of various ways to work with pipes in python, however they are too complicated to understand. What i would like is to write something like this:

```
import os

for cmdoutput_line in os.system('find /'):
  print cmdoutput_line
```

what is simplest way to achieve it without waiting+big-buffering command output? i dont want to wait while command finish, i just want to iterate output in real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def os_system(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        yield line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for path in os_system("find /tmp"):
        print path
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the closest and simplest to use method!

Answer (score 2):

In a **while** statement you can read line by line with **subprocess**,

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

process = Popen('find /', stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT, shell = True)
while True:
  line = process.stdout.readline()
  if not line: break
  print line
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can iterate on `process.stdout` just like any other file-like object.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import subprocess

sp = subprocess.Popen('find /', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
results = sp.communicate()
print results
```